# Resizing the iframe after form submit doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html file. I have a form which upon submit should call the foo() function. The foo() function should make the iframe cover the whole page. But it doesn't work. It only works if I call the only line in the foo() function from the Javascript console in Chrome.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
                body, html
                {
                    margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
                }
    
                #content
                {
                    position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px;
                }
        </style>
      </head>
    
      <script>
          function foo() {
            document.getElementById("content").style = "display: inline-block;"
          }
      </script>
    
      <body>
        <form id="form1" onsubmit="foo()">
          <input type="text" name="q" id="q" />
          <input type="submit" id="search" value="Search" />
        </form>
    
        <div id="content" style="display: none;" >
          <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://example.com/" />
        </div>
    
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What behavior do you noticed, it also could be because iframe is new embed document

Answer (score 0):

That is because after submitting, the page gets reloaded. You should use php to manage form submits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a fiddle like this, you echo the response and prevent the page from reloading. You can probably apply the same behavior in your app by returning false.

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" actopm="/echo/html/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="q" id="q" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<div id="content">
  <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://example.com/" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
var form = document.forms.form1;

form.onsubmit = function() {
  document.getElementById("content").style = "display: inline-block;"
  return false;
}
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#form1 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/r5nL20gz/1/